# GPUImage HoughTransformLineDetector Flickering / Flashing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gpuimage

I'm using GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector from Brad Larson's sample project in one of my apps that uses Storyboards.  Everything's working, but the screen flashes with this filter. When using the slider the flashing stops.  Can someone please help? Or does anyone know why this is happening?

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GPUImage.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<GPUImageVideoCameraDelegate>{
    GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera;
    GPUImageView *filterView;
    GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter;
 __unsafe_unretained UISlider *slider;
}
@property(readwrite, unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
- (IBAction)updateSlider:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
}
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize slider;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

CGRect mainScreenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
UIView *primaryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainScreenFrame];
primaryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.view = primaryView;

filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(primaryView.frame.origin.x,primaryView.frame.origin.y, primaryView.frame.size.width,primaryView.frame.size.height)];
[primaryView addSubview:filterView];
[filterView addSubview:slider];
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

[slider setMinimumValue:0.2];
[slider setMaximumValue:1.0];
[slider setValue:0.6];

filter = [[GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector alloc] init];
[(GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector *)filter setLineDetectionThreshold:0.60];
[filter addTarget:filterView];
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];

GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
[blendFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];
GPUImageGammaFilter *gammaFilter = [[GPUImageGammaFilter alloc] init];
[videoCamera addTarget:gammaFilter];
[gammaFilter addTarget:blendFilter];
[blendFilter addTarget:filterView];

GPUImageLineGenerator *lineGenerator = [[GPUImageLineGenerator alloc] init];
[lineGenerator forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];
[lineGenerator setLineColorRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0];
[(GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector *)filter setLinesDetectedBlock:^(GLfloat* lineArray, NSUInteger linesDetected, CMTime frameTime){
[lineGenerator renderLinesFromArray:lineArray count:linesDetected frameTime:frameTime];
}];
[lineGenerator addTarget:blendFilter];
[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
videoCamera.runBenchmark = YES;
}

- (IBAction)updateSlider:(id)sender {
[videoCamera resetBenchmarkAverage];
[(GPUImageHoughTransformLineDetector *)filter setLineDetectionThreshold:[(UISlider*)sender value]];
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No,  Ive put it on hold for now.   What about you... anything?

Comment: Not yet. I can find and show the lines, but it still is flickering.